# How does an atomizer work?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, bernoulli-equation

Will someone please explain how a basic [pump atomizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomizer_nozzle) works? I have a feeling it has something to do with pressure and the Venturi effect, but I'd really like to know precisely how they work as completely as possible.

If you know, please feel free to use [this image](http://www.sks-bottle.com/sprayDetDia.gif) as a reference in explaining.

EDIT: Please note that I'd specifically like to know how atomizers of the type pictured in the link I provided, the kind with a spring-based finger pump, work. I'm not talking about e-cigarette atomizers or [atomizers with the bulb design](http://www.beautypackaging.com/articles/2009/12/images/Powder-Bulb-Atomizer-008-%283%29.jpg).

Comment: I don't think the venturi is the main gig here, aside from as an energy source to get the fluid moving. What you need to explain is why the liquid shivvers into thousands of tiny droplets, and this must be something to do with turbulence, either in the liquid or the air at the air-liquid surface. Therefore, I don't believe the main thrust of this good question is different for bulb design or pump atomisers - the same basic question stands for both- why and how does the liquid shivver like it does?

Comment: That is a good point, but still not the point of my question. The Venturi effect *does* explain how the liquid travels up and out of a bulb-type atomizer, but until someone connects the effect to the pump-type, I don't see how it could explain what happens in a pump-type atomizer.

Answer (score 2):

because fluids flow faster through narrow spaces causing reduced pressure. Also because when you push a lever pressure pushes up and water comes out