# Pressure Variations in an Atomizer

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, bernoulli-equation

This question has been asked two times

1. [Similar question 1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/79039/how-does-an-atomizer-work)
2. [Similar question 2](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394572/how-does-this-spray-gun-work)

Now my question will be different from all those questions, since I will be asking where exactly I am having trouble understanding the working of an atomizer rather than just asking explain the working of atomizer.

While deriving equation of efflux , we take the pressure of liquid to be at the atmospheric pressure i.e $P_2= P_o$
[image]

Now when I am applying this logic to an atomizer, I am getting a contradiction :

[image: Atomizer]

Now the liquid at the horizontal level below the height is at $P_o$ . Since pressure increases with depth

$P_o>P_1$.

When we look at the horizontal tube in order to liquid to flow  $P_3>P_1>\mathbf P_o$ . Now this leads to an absurd result as earlier i have shown $P_o>P_1$ but here $P_1>P_0$

Why the pressure  end of horizontal tube is $P_o$?

As it was how we derived it in equation efflux.

**My question**

Why the pressure at the end of horizontal tube is not $P_0$? I am assuming that assuming that me taking  pressure $P_o$ at the end of the horizontal tube is my only mistake . If there is any other mistake please point out freely.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $P_3>P_1>P_o$ is not true.

The velocity of the liquid decreases from going to $P_1 to P_0$ . The pressure difference is not enough to stop the liquid from flowing out the tube.